# Using ".stringsdict" file with 'localizedStringWithFormat' --> Are NUMERALS localized for you?

Tags: localization, nsstring, nsnumberformatter, nslocalizedstring, plural

I am trying to produce the following localized string:

"In ___ day(s)"  -->  (ex: In 5 days)

To accomplish this, I've gone down the **.stringsdict** route:

```
<key>In %d Days</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringLocalizedFormatKey</key>
        <string>%#@Days@</string>
        <key>Days</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSStringFormatSpecTypeKey</key>
            <string>NSStringPluralRuleType</string>
            <key>NSStringFormatValueTypeKey</key>
            <string>d</string>
            <key>zero</key>
            <string>Today</string>
            <key>one</key>
            <string>In %d Day</string>
            <key>other</key>
            <string>In %d Days</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I then use the following, to obtain a localized string:

```
NSInteger days = ...;
localizedDueDateString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"In %d Days", @"Indicates days"),ABS(days)];
```

This correctly outputs a string that accounts for plurality.  For example:

```
In 1 day
In 4 days
```

I am wondering if the "1" and the  "4" here will be localized correct.  Other languages, like Arabic for example, have different symbols for their numerals.  I would expect the above string to use the symbol "٤" instead of "4", for arabic.

I know this can be accomplished using an NSNumberFormatter, but how can I accomplish numeral localization while ALSO respecting plurality visa vi a .stringsdict file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YES**

Numerals do appear to be correctly swapped when using a .stringsdict file in coordination with "localizedStringWithFormat" method!

I switched my iPad language to Arabic, and the output for

```
In 1 day
```

was...

```
١ day In
```

I don't have an arabic localization done yet, so "In" and "day" are english, but the numeral appears to be correctly localized.  No need for NSNumberFormatter